# SonarQube is not starting on SynologyNAS due to CONFIG_SECCOMP

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, sonarqube

SonarQube is unable to start on Synology NAS Docker due to the CONFIG_SECCOMP not being present on Synology NAS. Is there an option to ignore SECCOMP for SonarQube while it's starting ElasticSearch?

```
2022-11-26T11:00:50.430590094Z  stdout  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: seccomp unavailable: CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel, CONFIG_SECCOMP and CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER are needed
2022-11-26T11:00:50.429641210Z  stdout  2022.11.26 11:00:50 WARN  es[][o.e.b.JNANatives] unable to install syscall filter: 
2022-11-26T11:00:47.894977919Z  stdout  2022.11.26 11:00:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to start ElasticSearch additional configuration file must be also mounted: `sonar.properties` this file is located in `/opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties` and contains option `sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=`.

```
sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false
```

ElasticSearch allows to [disable SECCOMP check](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/_system_call_filter_check.html), but it's unsafe. By default this configuration can be amended in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yaml` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53051666/2529486)